# Does Twitterbot follow url redirects for Twitter Cards?

Tags: php, redirect, twitter, metadata, twitter-card

I'm setting up Twitter Cards for my website. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards

We have a custom short url that our tweet buttons post which redirects to a SEO friendly url.

My question is, do I need to add the metadata markup on both the redirect page and the final page?

I am using PHP's header:location(); to redirect to the SEO friendly page.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, redirected URLs are followed automatically by Twitter, so you only need to integrate Twitter Cards on the permalink:

See here (using a bit.ly URL to a 500px page with Twitter Cards integrated):

[image: Twitter Cards with redirecting URL]

Answer (score 2):

@Dan Leveille was correct,

However In late 2013 around the time Twitter added "summary-large" cards, I believe this changed. I ended up having to add the meta tags to both the short URL pages and the actual pages.

FYI, for anyone else in the future.